# How can I get data iterate Json?

Tags: javascript, json

I need get data the my Json but I can't use 'key' because the 'key' is different each day.

[image]

I tried :

```
template: function(params) {
        const objects = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params.data.masterdetail));
        for (const obj of objects) {
          const keys = Object.keys(obj);
          const cont = 0;
          keys.forEach(key => {
            const valor = obj[key];
            console.log('value ', valor[0]); 
          });
        }
```

I first tried with 0 and then use cont, but with 0 `console.log (value is undefined)....`

If I use `console.log ('value' , valor['name'])` IT'S OK ! but **I can't use keys** and if I use  valor[0] is undefined...........

Example Json

```
{

 "headers": [ 
   "headerName": "asdasd",
 ],   //end headers

  "datas": [

  "idaam": "11",
  "idorigen": "11",

   "masterdetail": [{
        "child1": {
          "name": "I AM",
          "age": "1"

        },

        "child2": {
          "name": "YOU ARE",
          "age": "2"
        },

        "child3": {
        "name": "HE IS",
        "age": "3"
        },
    }] //end masterdetail

  ]//end datas

}//end JSON
```

Edit :

I can't use 'keys' because today I receive "name", "typeval" etc. and tomorrow I can get 'surname','id' etc.

If you see in my first img you can see "4" bits of data.

```
1º obj[key]{
name = "adopt",
typeval= "",
etc
}
2º obj[key]{
"link" = "enlace",
"map" = "map"
etc
}
```

If I use this code : I get "name" OKEY but

I HAVE PROHIBITED use of `value['name']` or `value[typeval]` because this Json always is dynamic.

```
var objects = params.data.masterdetail[0];
        const keys = Object.keys(objects);
        let value;

        keys.forEach(key => {
          value = objects[key];
          console.log(value['name']);
          console.log(value['typeval']);
        });
```

I need for example :

```
 var objects = params.data.masterdetail[0];
        const keys = Object.keys(objects);
        cont = 0 ;

        keys.forEach(key => {
          value = objects[key];
          console.log(value[0]);
        });
```

but `value[0]` is undefined and then when I arrive `2ºobj[key]` link is index 0 but cont maybe is .... 4...

Sorry for my English...

Comment: Doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify` is totally pointless. You'll get back exactly what you put in. `const objects = params.data.masterdetail;` will give exactly the same result as your code. Do you understand what those two functions do?

Comment: Anyway you forgot to tell us what results you're expecting from your code?

Comment: Oh and your JSON is invalid, that can't be your real data. It looks like `headers` and `datas` (grammar yuk, "data" is already a plural!! The singular is "datum", technically, although "data" is often used for both, but "datas" is never used.) should be objects, not arrays.

Comment: what I do ?  ....

Answer (score 1):

To simply print the objects within the first entry in the masterdetail array, you can do the following:

```
var objects = params.datas.masterdetail[0];
const keys = Object.keys(objects);
keys.forEach(key => {
  console.log('value ', objects[key]); 
});
```

Based on a (suitably corrected - see my comments above) version of the JSON above, this would produce console output as follows:

```
value  {name: "I AM", age: "1"}
value  {name: "YOU ARE", age: "2"}
value  {name: "HE IS", age: "3"}
```

Unfortunately it's not 100% clear from the question if this is the output you were looking for, but that's my best guess based on the code.

Your main mistakes were that

1) `masterdetail` is an array, and all the data is within the first element of that array, so to get the objects within it you need to select that element first. If the array can have multiple elements in real life then you'd need an outer loop around the code above to iterate through it.

2) If you're looping through the keys of an object, you don't need to also iterate through the properties a different way. You seemed to have two loops designed to do the same thing.

Comment: I need get all fields "child1,child12,child3..." the master detail without keys

Comment: What do you mean "without keys" please? As you can see this code does not need to know the name of the keys in advance. If you mean something else, please describe _exactly_ what you want the output to be. You should also edit the question to include it because right now it really is not clear. And also please update your JSON to be valid and reflect your real data.

Comment: So I think you just need to see if each `objects[key]` (in my code) is itself an object, and if so then you iterate those keys as well and print the corresponding values. So another loop is called for within the existing one. Can you figure that out? If not then let me know, I can update the answer.

Comment: Right, so have a go...you can discover on google how to check if a variable is an object. Then you just need to write another loop similar to the one I've shown, but it iterates over the result of `object[key]` instead. Try it. If you can't work it out, update your code with what you've done, and I'll help again. I think you could learn it for yourself from this point, it's worth trying to understand it for yourself.